# ng-class class name which contains a scope variable rendered as null

Tags: angularjs, ng-class, angularjs-http

I have a  which utilizes classes based on a particular scope variable.

In this case, the scope variable is **{{jobSingle.UserFit.Summary.score}}** which takes on the values of **-1** (when unknown) or **0-10** (when score is known).

The span is rendered with the following code.

```
<span ng-class="{true: 'fit-score-{{jobSingle.UserFit.Summary.score * 10}}', false: 'fit-score-unknown'}[jobSingle.UserFit.Summary.score > -1]">
    [Content]
</span>
```

However, the class is not populated correctly for when jobSingle.UserFit.Summary.score > -1.

When I inspect the element in the Developer Console, the code is displaying as such.

```
<span class="fit-score-null" ng-class="{true: 'fit-score-70', false: 'fit-score-unknown'}[jobSingle.UserFit.Summary.score > -1]">
    [Content]
</span>
```

The class that was rendered for the span was 'fit-score-**null**'.

**Some other background info:**

The above code ***used to work*** when I was using mock data defined locally.

However, after having switched my controllers to call live data from an API using **$http**, null started appearing in my class name for the above situation.

All other data apart from the above renders perfectly.

Am I doing something wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: From the way you have it set up, your class should be either "true" or "false". From your ng-class, you are saying that use a class=true when the first expression is satisfied and use a class=false when the 2nd expression is satisfied. If both are satisfied then both true and false will appear as classes. Do you want your class attribute to have true/false or fit-score-* ?

Comment: @RahulGarg The class attribute should be fit-score-*. The answer I selected below did the trick. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not evaluate (use  {{ and }}) inside an angular version attribute since it will already evalutate the value - just like your write 'fit-score-' it will already evaluate that into a string. Try this instead

```
ng-class="{true : 'fit-score-' + (jobSingle.UserFit.Summary.score * 10), false : ...
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked. Turned out it had nothing to do with local data versus data retrieved from $http. (: